# How to retrive comment_replies from table in django

Tags: python, sql, django

I am doing the comment part of the blog API. I can't derive replies, but I could derive the comments.

**Python module: Django:**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self', related_name='reply', null=True, blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

[image: Database table for above shown Django code]

Above is the table and shows the comments that are stored using the Django Comment model code.

**My task:** I have the id of the parent comment. And I have to derive the rest of the RED box.

Anything is welcome: Idea, SQL script, or Django Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a property on model named 'replies' and it will give all replies on those comments.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self', related_name='reply', null=True, blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def replies(self):
        return Comment.objects.filter(parent_id=self.id)
```

So let's assume you have a parent comment and you need all replies on that comment

```
parent = Comment.objects.get(id=1)
# Replies on this comment is.
print(parent.replies) # It will have only one comment in array with id=9
```

Now if you need replies on comment with `id=9`

```
parent.replies[0].replies # It will give comments with id 10 and 11
```

Update: If you need all nested replies directly, you can do similar to Django-admin do during the deletion of an object. It first shows you all affected objects

```
from django.contrib.admin.utils 
collector = NestedObjects(using='default')
collector.collect(parents)
print(collector.data[parents[0].__class__]) # It will print all nested objects comments.
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, If I wanted to get all replies at once, is there any way of doing it?

Comment: you mean all nested replies?

Comment: I had tried what you wrote above before asking question

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about it

Comment: No, there is no direct way of it. you need to write a recursive function for it.

Comment: Thanks I will try then

Comment: @Madiyor Check the updated part, it will give you all nested comments.